# Mysql second JOIN returning empty array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I seached 2 good hours trying to solve this but nothing I found worked.
I have 3 tables:

```
recipe              recipe_ingredient                recipe_steps
id                  id                               id
name                recipe_id                        recipe_id
description         ingredient_name                  step_description
sort_order          ingred_order                     step_order
```

If I join only recipe and recipe_steps it works fine

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipe 
JOIN recipe_steps ON recipe.id = recipe_steps.recipe_id
```

If I try to JOIN recipe_ingredient, i get an empty array

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipe 
JOIN recipe_steps ON recipe.id = recipe_steps.recipe_id 
JOIN recipe_ingredient ON recipe.id = recipe_ingredient.recipe_id
```

This is the rest of my code:

```
 <?php 
  $query = "SELECT * FROM recipe JOIN recipe_steps ON recipe.id =   recipe_steps.recipe_id JOIN recipe_ingredient ON recipe.id = recipe_ingredient.recipe_id";  
  $recipe = $mysqli->query($query);
  if(!$result){echo mysql_error();}
  ?>
```

```
  <?php  while($result = $recipe->fetch_assoc()){ 
   //var_dump($result);
   $k = 0;
   $nr = 1;
   $desc = json_decode($result["step_description"],true);  ?>

<li> 
    <h2> <?php echo $result["name"]; ?> </h2>
    <p class="recipe_date">22/03/2013</p>
    <p class="recipe_date">Categorii:</p>
    <p><?php echo $result["description"]; ?></p>
    <p>Timp preparare: <?php echo $result["hours"] . " h  " . $result["minutes"] . " m"; ?></p>

    <?php foreach($desc as $row){ ?>
    <p class="list_pasi"><i>Pasul <?php echo $nr; ?></i>: <?php echo $desc[$k]; ?></p>
    <?php $k++; $nr++;
        }    ?>    
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

recipe:

[image]

recipe_steps:

[image]

recipe_ingredients:

[image]

Comment: Does `mysql_error()` give any errors?

Comment: show us a http://sqlfiddle.com/ example

Comment: would be helpful with some table data/content.

Comment: If you run that query in your mysql client does it give any results?

Comment: @Mihai  In phpmyadmin i get nothing, no results.

Comment: Probably not a code problem,post table screenshots.

Comment: @RobertIulian Salut,to make a join you need a column with identical values in both tables,this ON recipe.id = recipe_ingredient.recipe_id is simply the condition of the JOIN,both id and receipe_id have to have the same data.If one is empty there is nothing to JOIN on.

Comment: Fixed that issue. Posted links to tables(Not enough rep for direct upload). Now i get a duplicate of my entire loop and data from recipe_ingredients is still unavailable.

Comment: The sql is fine...I guess theres's a problem with my script... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6dc86/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is that the `recipe_ingredient` table is empty.

As a side note: When it finally works, you will get a cartesian product of steps and ingredients for each recipe. Are you certain that this is what you really want?

Comment: I'm new to relational databases and to programming. What I want is to make a search based on ingredients. This is what I came up with. And yes the ingredient table is empty :( .I'll check on my insert query.

Comment: if its empty what did you expect?!?

Comment: @Robert: Then you should base your search solely on the ingredient table, retrieve some recipe ids and _then_ select the appropriate recipes to display. Also, if this answer helped you, please accept it.

Comment: Its a bit more complicated. When the user submits a  new recipe he has a autoincrement ingredient table(ingredient_name,quantity, value) And with this he can add any number of ingredients. I still need to display them on the detailed recipe page.

Comment: I think it shouldn't be that complicated, but hey, your app, your logic. Right?

Comment: I'm learning as I go. Started only about 2 moths ago. Anyway your awnswer was correct,the query was good, the problem was the empty ingredient table.Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. And thanks for accepting. Concerning your application logic, IMHO you should post another question, since _that_ would be irrelevant to your original post. Rest assured, many (including me) would come to your aid. Keep up!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   recipe r 
       JOIN recipe_steps rs 
         ON r.id = rs.recipe_id 
       JOIN recipe_ingredient ri 
         ON r.id = ri.recipe_id;
```

Comment: Whats the difference between your query and his query ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using LEFT JOIN instead of the both JOINs.

Comment: I get the same result.